# open source time series sales data for forecasting

Tags: time-series, dataset, forecasting

I'm looking for open source time series sales data (past 2-3 yrs or more) that contains at least the following variables.

```
1. Date: the date of Sales
2. Product: multiple products, sub-types
3. Store / department: multiple stores
4. Promo (week, year)
5. Promo Interval
6. Competition Open Since(month, year)
7. Competition Distance
8. Level of Assortment
9. Number of Customers
```

Also, the following external variables (not limited to) that may affect sales:

```
1. Marketing Cost
2. Advertisement Cost
3. Research Cost
4. Inflation
5. Seasonality
6. Weather
7. Is holiday
```

The goal is to predict sales for next year, and to analyze the effect of external variables on the predicted sales. I tried searching in `datasetsearch`, `kaggle`, `data.world` etc. but yet to find a comprehensive dataset. I'd appreciate if you could give some pointers.